# How to find the correct sum formula s [n] for a sequence a [n] with all positive numbers?

Tags: differential-equations

Known:
A sequence a [n] with all positive terms, if the sum of the first n terms of the sequence a [n] is s [n], and `s[1] ==a [1]==1, Sqrt [s [n]+Sqrt [s [n-1]==s [n] - s [n-1]`, find the first n terms of the sequence a [n] and the formula s [n]

```
Sqrt[s[n]] + Sqrt[s[n - 1]] == s[n] - s[n - 1], s[1] == 1
```

Using code to calculate s [n] has two results：

```
ClearAll["`*"]
RSolve[{Sqrt[s[n]] + Sqrt[s[n - 1]] == s[n] - s[n - 1], s[1] == 1}, 
 s[n], n]
```

get the two results:

```
{{s[n] -> (-2 + n)^2}, {s[n] -> n^2}}
```

According to the meaning of the question,`{{s[n] -> (-2 + n)^2}` this answer is clearly incorrect.

Because all terms in the sequence are positive, that is, each term is greater than 0

`a[1]>0,a[2]>0,a[3]>0......a[n]>0`

if

`{{s[n] -> (-2 + n)^2}`

then,

`a[1]==s[1]==1>0,s[2]==a[1]+a[2]==1+a[2]==0,so a[2]==-1<0`.

above all this answer  incorrect.

According to the meaning of the question, there is only one correct answer:

```
{s[n] -> n^2}}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous (exactly the same) question which already had several comments, including a possible solution?!

Comment: I noticed that there are two posts that have been closed, and if they are closed, there is no way to continue the discussion. In retrospect, Bob's answer should be close to the solution.

Comment: The question was not yet closed, it only had 2 (out of 5 needed) close votes. And even if the question gets closed, it happens for a reason (!) – and it can also be reopened if the question is corrected. Please, do not do this again.

Comment: @Domen Thank you for your reminder. Comment on the issue is also a necessary path to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. This is incorrect: "[a]ccording to the meaning of the question,`{{s[n] -> (-2 + n)^2}` this answer is clearly incorrect." The statement `RSolve[{Sqrt[s[n]] + Sqrt[s[n - 1]] == s[n] - s[n - 1], s[1] == 1}, s[n], n]` is the only *question* that Mathematica sees. There is no domain specification there. Mathematica found and provided two solutions to that question.
2. This is a good time to read the documentation for [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html):

[image: Documentation fragment]

3. This gives only the desired answer:

```
ClearAll["`*"];
RSolve[{Sqrt[s[n]] + Sqrt[s[n - 1]] == s[n] - s[n - 1], s[1] == 1, 
  s[2] == 4}, s[n], n]
(* {{s[n] -> n^2}} *)
```